# Traverse list of related tables

Tags: mysql, hyperlink

I have a peculiar situation. In my MySQL database, I have around 90 odd tables and most of the tables have been indexed (We are using INNODB). Some of the tables are having a link like this:

A -> B -> C->D->E

Is there a way where-in I can find the list of all the sub-child tables when i have only table A and E to work with?  I have do a dynamic query builder mechanism, and for that purpose I list the users with the list of tables, and in a given situation like above, need to get the required information from just table "A" and "E" alone, without the tables "B","C" and "D" being selected by the search user.

The tables are linked in normal manner..each table is linked to another via a proper foreign key constraint.

Eg. 
Table A (Transaction)
Id, Trxn-Date, Amount

Table B (Transaction Header)
Id, Agent_Id (FK to Agent_Profile), Upd_Time, Trnx_Hdr_ID (FK to Table A)

Table C (Agent_Profile)
Id, Prof_ID (FK to Profile)

Table D (Profile)
ID, Pers_Info_Id (FK to Personal_Info)

Table E (Personal_Info)
Id, Firstname, Lastname

User selects **Trxn_Date, FirstName, LastName**.

How can I retrieve the sub-linked table information, when the selected tables(in this case), happens to be only **Transaction** and **Personal_Info**.

Comment: Are these tables glued together by external keys?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could consolidate a few of those tables into 2-3 tables without losing anything useful. Tables C D and E just contain columns to point to other tables.

If changed, a query with trxn_date and first/last name would be a ton easier.

Comment: As of now, the structures cannot be restructured. It has been running up for a long time. What i have added up on the description is just a few. Actually the tables have more data, for brevity i  had just added few columns. My requirement is to get the list of all the intermediate tables between A and E. Do you get the requirement?